# I got a Error during my Todos project : Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/ :404 Not Found

Tags: angular, typescript

I get the error while i get run my Delete part:[image]
Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/$%7Bthis.todosUrl%7D/$%7Btodo.id%7D: 404 Not Found

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: How you navigating ? It seems like you are using `{ }` where it is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you're doing:

```
'http://localhost:4200/{{this.todosUrl}}/{{todo.id}}'
```

Or

```
'http://localhost:4200/${this.todosUrl}/${todo.id}'
```

Try changing to:

```
`http://localhost:4200/${this.todosUrl}/${todo.id}`
```

Comment: or use `router.navigate` or `routerLink`?

Comment: @UmutEsen It's unclear whether the OP is navigating or making an API request.. :/

Comment: During runtime, The part in the Url works good.But the source file,added do not work.